# How to pull data from two CSV files into a main file making sure all data shows up in correct rows?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a main file that compiles descriptive information of a soil sample and then the data from an analysis of the soil sample. This file is made from a csv file with info on sample like coordinates, name of site etc and then when we get the data from analysis the data gets matched per sample in the main file. The sample reference column header in the two files is different just due to software for sampling and format used by external lab, but the sample reference numbers are same. I want code that can read the csv files and identify the matching sample reference numbers from the differing columns, match them up and import the rest of the rows data and match that data to the column headers in the main file and essentially fill the datasheet. This may mean manually matching up column header code, that is okay.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add some more information about the files, the desired output and your code so far ([minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: I believe you want [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.